# How can I print out samples of message templates?

Tags: message-templates

I want to be able to compare various messages for inconsistencies in messaging.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you explained a bit more about the types of messages eg Scheduled Reminders? System Template Messages (eg receipts)? standard 'mail' templates?

Answer (score 1):

One tool that can help is the [Transactional Email extension](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional) by Fuzion which ensures that anything that goes out, including receipts etc, are recorded in civicrm as an Activity so you can 'see' what went out.

Currently civi doesn't offer a way to 'preview' the System Message Templates.

NOTE: recent blog about above extension [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/did-that-scheduled-reminders-get-delivered-or-did-it-bounce-and-what-was-in-those).

Comment: The Extension notes list this as good for 4.6 CiviCRM. Do you know if it works for 4.7.x?